# Eclipse CDT – Application wide theme configuration

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I've recently started using Eclipse CDT.

After some searching, I've found a way to change its source view theme by importing a .epf file from the File menu.  However when I launch another Eclipse instance and create a new project, that theme is lost (it goes back to the default white background).

How can I perform application wide theme configuration in Eclipse CDT?  I want all my Eclipse instances to have the same appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, here is one way:

1. Download preference file (.epf file) from somewhere (e.g., http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/)
2. Import it from File -> Import -> General -> Preferences
3. Optionally set additional preferences from Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring
4. Save new preferences to preference file from File -> Export -> General -> Preferences
5. Import this preference file after creating new project

Not perfect but it works.